# CSS Problems with centering assets

Tags: html, css

So I'm also a total noob with CSS, and I'm getting confused on how to center my logo. It worked on my footer but not on my text / logo.

Also, how to fix that small bit on the left of my footer, I already set the .footer width to 100%.

Thanks!

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Konvoy</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>
<!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href="/css/normalize.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4/leaflet.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <header> <!--<div id="logo">--> <h1><img src="/assets/Konvoy Logo.png" width="350"/> <!--</div>--> </h1>
<div class="description" style="margin-top: 0px;">See each other in any situation. Geolocation App For Everyone.</div>
</header>
<div class="content">

</div>


<!-- <div class="app">
<div id="infobox" class="infobox"></div> -->


<!-- <div id="map">To get this app to work you need to share your geolocation.</div> 
</div> -->
</div> 
<div class="footer" style="padding-top: 30px;"><center> 2013 All Rights Reserved. Team Konvoy </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/application.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   background: url('../assets/landing_page_bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   color: #666;
   @font: 14px/18px 'Bariol', Arial, sans-serif;
 }

.container{

}

header {
  text-align: center;
  position: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;

} 

.description {
   font-weight: 300;
   font: 24px 'Bariol', Arial, sans-serif;
   color: #006794;
   text-align: center; 
}

.content {

}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #039686;
  font: 16px 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: To remove the gap between your footer and the window, just do this: `body { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ this is a good start- makes sure your footer always stays at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

## HTML

```
<h1 id="logo"><img src="/assets/Konvoy Logo.png" width="350"/>
```

## CSS

```
h1#logo {
    width:350px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="/assets/Konvoy Logo.png" width="350" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:100px;margin-left:-175px;"/>
```

Also, adding a CSS Reset sheet to your page will help solve many problems, such as default page margins.

http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: No, using absolute positioning isn't a good way to centre elements.

Comment: Why not? Don't see any problem using absolute in this situation. When pointing out, please also give an description why.

Comment: Thanks @Sven, I don't understand why "absolute positioning isn't a good way to centre elements"

Comment: Absolute positioning should only be used where really needed. It does not block elements, so it's height, margin, padding is completely disregarded. In this case there are simple alternatives, which maintain block. There are certain cases where position absolute is fine to use, and even this techique to centre an element. But not to centre an element which flows in the page, like the site logo.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   background: url('../assets/landing_page_bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   color: #666;
   @font: 14px/18px 'Bariol', Arial, sans-serif;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #039686;
  font: 16px 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 100;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to keep footers at the bottom of the page.

```
.footer { 
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

**Reference:** [How to keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

[Demo](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways one can center an element in css.

1. If the element's width is known we may center it using `margin: auto;`
2. If there is a need to use absolute or fixed positioning and the width of the element is known then we can center it like so:

   ```
   .logo {
   width: 350;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin: 0 0 0 -175px; // width/2
   }
   ```
3. Using `text-align: center;` on the parent container.
   In this case - make sure the parent container and its children are in the normal flow (not floated and not positioned). And the child element needs to be `inline` or `inline-block`.

**Edit:**
And one more thing: in your `header` tag you first open a `div`, then an `h1` tag, but the closing order is not correct. You need to close the `h1` first and only then the `div` ;)